# generalized linear eigenvalue problem with more eigenvalues than the number of dimensions?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

for the the $n \times n$ problem $Ax = \lambda x$, the number of eigenvalues is at most $n$, I believe. However, what can be said about the generalized problem $Ax = \lambda Bx$?

The reason I am asking is that in my work, I've come across an example that seems to have more than $n$ eigenvalues:

$A=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 5 & 0 & 8\\
13 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 5i & 0 & 8i\\
13i & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$

$B=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
0 & 1 & 0 & i\\
1 & 0 & i & 0\\
0 & i & 0 & -1\\
i & 0 & -1 & 0
\end{array}\right)$

has eigenvalues 13, 5, 0, -8i, and 0, with the first four eigenvectors being the columns of the $4 \times 4$ identity matrix, while the 5th eigenvector being

$x=\left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\
8\\
0\\
-5
\end{array}\right)$

I have two questions:
1) are there actually five different eigenpairs here, or is one of them spurious or illegitimate in some way?
2) what general things can be said about the number of possible eigenpairs for generalized linear eigenvalue problems like this?

Comment: Don't know why this question didn't receive any attention. For me it seems to be extremely interesting. For example, we still can't have more then $n$ eigenvalues, since $\det(A-\lambda B)$ is polynom of order $n$. Also seems, that if $A$ is symmetric and $B$ is positive-defined we can't have more than $n$ eigenvectors.